# Pain and Angina Pectoris

Tags: cardiology, pain

What causes pain in an angina pectoris? Ok, heart muscles may lack oxygen, but what is the role of pain here? Is it being beneficial? I'd like to know the physiological process of induction of pain during hypoxia.